# How do I use a custom SVG file with material-ui Icon Component?

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, icons, material-ui

In my project, I am using custom `svg` files as part of the requirement.
I am using `material-ui@3.9.3` to achieve this.
I looked at the example that is available on the official documentation -> https://material-ui.com/style/icons/#svg-icons

However, in my version, the custom icons do not appear the same way.
My forked version is available at https://codesandbox.io/s/mqnq9qrqn8

What I am looking for is a way to use the custom icons that can work well with Material-UI's `<Icon>` Component.

Could someone please help me with this?
Thank you

Answer (score 17):

You can also use the Material-UI **IconButton** component and wrap it around your svg img as shown below

```
import React from 'react'
import { Icon } from "@material-ui/core";
import YourLogo from './yourlogo.svg'

export const Logo = () => (
    <Icon>
        <img src={YourLogo} height={25} width={25}/>
    </Icon>
)
```

Comment: Note: you have to specify the height and width or the svg will not appear. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 9):

You can import the svg file as a React Component and then use it directly inside an SvgIcon Component from Material UI.
This will also allow you to style your component.

```
import React from 'react';
import { SvgIcon, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';
import { ReactComponent as MySvg } from './img/someSvgFile.svg';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => {
  mySvgStyle:{
    fillColor: theme.palette.primary.main
  }
})

function MySvgIcon() {

  classes = useStyles();

  return(
    <SvgIcon className={classes.mySvgStyle}>
      <MySvg/>
    </SvgIcon>
  )
}
```

Comment: This method throws an error in more recent years: Module '"*.svg"' has no exported member 'ReactComponent'. Did you mean to use 'import ReactComponent from "*.svg"' instead? ts(2614)

Answer (score 5):

The answer lies in the viewBox attribute [( MDN )](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox)

When you are messing with SVGs, especially copy/pasted ones, you have to finesse the viewBox to frame your paths correctly. I usually start with `<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" />` and scale up or down, to taste. After some fiddling, `"0 0 60 50"` looks pretty good [(link)](https://codesandbox.io/s/98rll70wo4).

[image: tags]

Looking at the MaterialUI docs [(link)](https://material-ui.com/api/svg-icon/#props), they planned for this sort of thing and allow it as a prop on the component.

Comment: Thank you so very much. I wonder how can I get then in viewBox `0 0 24 24`

Comment: No problem. To change the size of the icon, you can just use the CSS properties, `width` and `height`. You could also add the attributes directly to `<SVGIcon />`. I updated the CodeSandbox to demonstrate (demo.js line 17). It's tricky for me to explain, but the way I think about viewBox is that it handles centering the paths within the SVG.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `createSvgIcon` utility from MUI to create custom svg icons. It can be used to wrap an svg or an svg path, which is passed as a child to the SvgIcon component:

For example:

```
const HomeIcon = createSvgIcon(
  <path d="M10 20v-6h4v6h5v-8h3L12 3 2 12h3v8z" />,
  'Home',
);
```

For more information, check out this [link](https://mui.com/material-ui/icons/#material-svg-icons).

Answer (score 0):

just put an `<img/>` inside your `<Icon/>` or any other widgets...

```
import { Icon } from "@material-ui/core"
import YourImage from './yourImage.png'
                                       
export const YourComponent = () => (
    <Icon>
        <img src={YourImage}/>
    </Icon>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me - an `img` tag inside a `fragment`:

```
import eraserIcon from "assets/svg/eraser.svg";
.
.
.
    <FormControlLabel
      value="female"
      control={
        <Radio
          value="sdfsdf"
          size="small"
          checkedIcon={
            <>
              <img alt="sd" src={eraserIcon} />
            </>
          }
          name="radio-buttons"
          inputProps={{ "aria-label": "B" }}
        />
      }
      label={"my-label"}
    />
```

inside the `checkedIcon` attribute that accepts a `React.ReactNode`.

I must say that **aapa320**'s solution and **Dinesh Nadimpalli**'s solution are much more elegant and flexible but I've tried them and the svg was no longer in the center, and its size changed.. so I had to do some extra work with it.
My solution is very simple but it is limited, use it only if you don't have to provide custom CSS.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me (I use js, not jsx but jsx should be similar I gues)

```
// add webpack loader for svg files
moduleLoaders.push({
    test: /\.svg$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: {
        loader: 'svg-react-loader',
    },
})
```

...

```
import React from "react";
import createSvgIcon from "@mui/material/utils/createSvgIcon";

function MenuLogo(logo, text, props) {
    return React.createElement(createSvgIcon(
        React.createElement(logo, null)
    , text), props)
}

// where logo is something like:
import logo from "path/to/logo.svg"

// and props is just whatever you'd like to pass through material UI, eg. {sx: ...}
```